The web page image is not fully displayed
In wkwebview，The web page image is not fully displayed, only part of it is rendered. Switch the app to the background and then to the foreground, and the incomplete image will be rendered correctly again.
enter image description here
The above is an example, the image already has height
The network is good, debugging in safri, you can preview the picture normally

Without seeing the relevant code we have no hope of being able to give a solid solution. Any answer will just be a guess. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
